# How do I remove the last folder from a given path in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have this code, but it doesn't seem to be working; I can't work out why:

```
set dir = %cd%
:char
set dir=%dir:~0,-1%
IF %dir:~-1%=="\" ( goto end ) else ( goto char )
:end
```

I have narrowed it down to the line

`set dir=%dir:~0,-1%`

which seems to be setting `dir` to `~0,-1`, but that doesn't make sense because I used the exact same line in another program, and it worked fine.

BTW: This code is meant to be removing the last folder name from the current directory path.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
set "dir=%cd%"
:char
set dir=%dir:~0,-1%
IF "%dir:~-1%"=="\" ( goto end ) else ( goto char )
:end
SET di
FOR /f %%a IN ("%cd%") DO SET "dir=%%~dpa"
SET di

GOTO :EOF
```

`set` recognises <kbd>Space</kbd> on each side of the assignment, hence you were assigning the current directory to "dir<kbd>Space</kbd>" and `dir` was not set at all.

Your `if` command was missing the quotes around the first argument.

Here's an easier way to do it...

Answer (score 3):

The actual problem in your code is that the variable `dir` is not assigned in the first line, its name is `dir` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>. You need to change it to `set dir=%cd%` or even `set "dir=%cd%"`.

---

To remove the last folder name from a given path, use a simple `for` loop and the `~dp` expansion (see `for /?`):

```
set "FOLDER=%CD%"
for /D %%D in ("%FOLDER%") do (
    set "PARENT=%%~dpD"
)
echo Last folder removed: %PARENT%
```

The is no need to split off character by character and search for `\` as you are doing.

**Note:**
I recommend not to use variable name `dir` to avoid confusion as there is an equally named internal command.

Comment: In case the trailing `\ `is disturbing, take a look at this post: [Remove trailing backslash from a path with batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67095328)…

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've done it easily by:

```
for %%a in (%FilePath%) do set "ParentDir=%%~dpa"
echo %ParentDir%
```

%%~dpa expands the %a to (d)drive and (p)path