# Remove trailing backslash from a path with batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, path

I have such a filename saved in a variable:

```
C:\Directory\Directory2\
```

And now I want to have this:

```
C:\Directory\Directory2
```

How to cut the last `\` from the filename or the last character?

Comment: I would ask how you defined that variable in the first place. The best way to deal with it is pre-definition, not post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, just don't! Removing the trailing backslash may change the target the path points to; think of `C:\` – which points to the *root directory* of the drive, while `C:` points to the *current directory* of it.

The most reliable way of dealing with potential trailing backslashes is probably to append `.`, because `C:\Directory\Directory2\` is equivalent to `C:\Directory\Directory2\.`, `C:\Directory\Directory2` and `C:\Directory\Directory2.`, because all these paths point to exactly the same location.

If the suffix disturbs for cosmetic reasons, resolve it by a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) after having appended `.`:

```
set "dirPath=C:\Directory\Directory2\"
for %%I in ("%dirPath%.") do echo "%%~fI"
```

The [modifier `~f`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) defines to resolve the path and also converts relative ones to full/absolute ones.

If the provided path may even end with `\.` or is something like `C:.`, appending another `.` would change its target; this however can be solved by another `for` loop before appending `.`:

```
set "dirPath=C:\Directory\Directory2\."
for %%J in ("%dirPath%") do for %%I in ("%%~fJ.") do echo "%%~fI"
```

Note that `for` resolves [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) like `?` and `*`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use substring expansion:

```
set "var=C:\Directory\Directory2\"
echo %var:~0,-1%
```

obviously there might be a case where the last character is not `\`. Therefore we rather test if it is the case, only then do we exclude it.

```
if "%var:~-1%" == "\" set "var=%var:~0,-1%"
```